# query to find 3 timestamps(ts) with 1st closest to the given ts and 2 closest to the 1st that was found

Tags: postgresql

Assuming the table has more than 5 timestamp. I want to get the closest timestamp to the given timestamp first than 2 other timestamps which are the closest previous and closest after of the 1st.
For example:
I have [3,1,4,2,5]. The closest timestamp to the first given one is 4 then it would give 3,4,5

Comment: What do you mean by the closest? Temporally speaking or literally their position on the table?

Comment: nice homework, maybe the function age may help.https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html

Comment: @GRoutar the nearest date to the given date. Sorry my English is not that good. like between 1/9/2020 and 1/20/2020, which one is the closest to 1/10/2020. Answer is 1/9/2020

Comment: @FatFreddy this is not homework haha nice guess but this is work.

Comment: Please review help section [ask]. Using this as a template for your question is more likely to get you a successful answer.  In particular here you say "table has more than 5 timestamp". Do you mean more than 5 timestamps on each row, or just more than 5 rows with timestamps? If 1 row, exactly how many? If multiple rows what makes 1sr, 2nd, etc? Further the 'sample data given is integers but the question concerns timestamps. How are these related? Using the integer data 3 is the 1st and you say 4 is the closest, but why not 2? Do you mean the closest greater than the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to find the closest timestamp to a given value

Assuming you have a simple table like that :

```
CREATE TABLE test (dt TIMESTAMP)
```

You can find the closest timestamp to, for example, '2014-12-31T23:59:59Z' by searching for the minimum interval between the timestamp in your base and your given value. For this you can use something like that:

```
SELECT dt AS closest_timestamp FROM test ORDER BY (
   CASE WHEN((dt - '2014-12-31T23:59:59Z'::TIMESTAMP) < INTERVAL '0')
   THEN (-(dt - '2014-12-31T23:59:59Z'::TIMESTAMP)) ELSE
   (dt - '2014-12-31T23:59:59Z') END) ASC LIMIT 1;
```

The 'CASE' part is used to have the interval in absolute value. And then you can just look for the closest before, and the closest after this value with something like this:

```
WITH f AS (SELECT dt FROM test ORDER BY (CASE WHEN (
   (dt - '2014-12-31T23:59:59Z'::TIMESTAMP) < INTERVAL '0')
   THEN (-(dt - '2014-12-31T23:59:59Z'::TIMESTAMP)) ELSE 
   (dt - '2014-12-31T23:59:59Z'::TIMESTAMP) END) ASC LIMIT 1)
SELECT 
   f.dt AS closest_first,
   b.dt AS just_before_closest_first,
   a.dt AS just_after_closest_first
FROM
   f,
   (SELECT dt FROM test WHERE dt < (SELECT dt FROM f) ORDER BY dt DESC LIMIT 1) AS b,
   (SELECT dt FROM test WHERE dt > (SELECT dt FROM f) ORDER BY dt ASC LIMIT 1) AS a;
```

There is some issues with this solution, especially if there is no value in your base before or after your first closest value, but globally it does the trick...

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I thought about this solution as well but I just split it into 3 queries. Do you think it would affect performance if I split this into 3 queries instead of 1 big query like this